# Cant make form date_select hidden in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to create a form which loads upon a user clicking a date in a calendar, the form then is passed the date that is clicked through the URL and the controller assigns that date to the `@date` variable. I then create a `date_select` element and assign it the `@date` variable. This works fine but since I do not want the user to be able to edit the date in the form I want it to be hidden.

I pass these html options to the form but it doesn't seem to ever effect the HTML:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :default => @date, :type => "hidden" %>
```

Am I missing something? I also tried passing it in an HTML hash `:html => { :type = "hidden" }` but that doesn't work either.  Even when I try something different like `:class => "something"` it doesn't change the HTML. Is there something special about the `date_select` helper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date_select` accepts the options `discard_day`, `discard_month` and `discard_year` to do exactly what you are trying to achieve.

```
<%= f.date_select :date, { :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true, :discard_year => true } %>
```

Behind the scenes, it generates the following HTML code:

```
<input id="record_date_3i" name="record[date(3i)]" type="hidden" value="5" />
<input id="record_date_2i" name="record[date(2i)]" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="record_date_1i" name="record[date(1i)]" type="hidden" value="2012" />
```

No CSS tricks, no changes in your controllers.

Comment: Nice! just what I was looking for

Comment: Can you use `discard_day: true, discard_month: true, discard_year: true, discard_hour: true, discard_minute: true` to extend this to `datetime_select`?

Answer (score 4):

Per the name, `date_select` generates `<select>` elements. In no version of (X)HTML does the `select` element support the `type` attribute. If you want a hidden form field then you should use the [`hidden_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) helper, which generates `<input type="hidden">` elements.

---

(To answer your implied question about using e.g. `:class => 'something'`, the problem is that the `options` and `html_arguments` parameters must be two separate hashes, but if you do something like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :default => @date, :class => 'something' %>
```

..the Ruby interpreter assumes that you have supplied a single hash, i.e. `{ :default => @date, :class => 'something' }` (and really, can you blame it?), and since `class` isn't a valid key for the `options` hash it's ignored. Instead you have to make it obvious to Ruby that these are two separate parameters by doing something like this instead:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :default => @date, { :class => 'something' } %>
<%# Hey Ruby, this is a different Hash! ----^                         %>
```

See the difference? Of course you could go bonkers and be *really* obvious, e.g.:

```
<%= f.date_select(:date, { :default => @date }, { :class => 'something' }) %>
```

..but that's ugly and egregious so don't bother.)

Comment: Just to provide a little more background, as Jordan mentioned rails helpers just generate the underlying HTML for your app http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html type is an attribute of this underlying HTML http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp and this is why it cannot be applied to the <select> that the date_select helper generates.

Comment: I think that was pretty clear, @maecro, but regardless [please don't link](http://w3fools.com/) to W3Schools. @Graeme, if you need more reference material, please refer to the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select), which lists the valid attributes for `<select>` elements. (W3Schools is not affiliated with the W3C.)

Comment: Thanks guys! This leads me to another question, Ive been trying to assign it to a hidden field and I am getting an error `undefined method "merge" for "Thu Dec 15 00:00:00 -0700 2011":String` I guess the hidden_field cant accept a date object. What is the best practice for passing a date in the field, do I actually have to break it up into 3 different hidden fields for MM DD YY, just like a date_select? or is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry I guess I should put @Jordan in the comment to direct it to you.

Comment: @Graeme It says "String," i.e. it's automatically stringifying the date, so that's likely not your problem. When are you getting this error? When you load the page with the form on it, or when you submit the form? What lines in your code does the error refer to? You may want to post this as a separate question, btw.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan I was getting the error when I would load the page, all good now though! It seems I just had to specify `:value => @date` and everything worked out. Maybe this is a necessity for hidden fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it inside a hidden div:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <%= f.date_select :date, :default => @date, :type => "hidden" %>
</div>
```

That will allow you to have all the fields and hidden you can also use for date and time select:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <%= f.datetime_select :date, :default => @date, :type => "hidden" %>
</div>
```